# Why would I update a value in a view?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Just a quick question on my MCSA SQL Server 2012 course.

As part of an exercise I've been asked to create a trigger to stop any updates on a view, I first checked that I could indeed change a value of a column on the view.

Having worked with views before I know what they are, but I dont know why a view wouldn't stop a change in the first place by default anyway.

1) Why might I want to change a value in the view table?

2) Also if I updated a value on the view, would anything change it back to reflect what is in the base tables and if so when might that happen?, ie an overnight refresh, any change to the base table?

Thanks :)

Comment: Near duplicate: [If I update a view, will my original tables get updated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648445/if-i-update-a-view-will-my-original-tables-get-updated)

Comment: (1) For convenience, or simply because you can. There may be hundreds of reasons why you may want to do it. (2) The data gets written back into the actual table.

Comment: Proper ways to make a view read only (instead of deliberately making it complex) can be found in [Creating readonly views in Sql Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805760/creating-readonly-views-in-sql-server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems to be more concerned with "why" rather than "how." Why would DML be executed against a view instead of directly against a table? The answers are almost too numerable to list here, but here are just a couple of the bigger ones.

For starters, when I design a database, almost every table has at least one view defined for it. If more than one, one is normally the DML view and the others are read-only (trigger that does nothing). No outward-facing and very few inward-facing apps have direct access to the tables. Everything must go through the views.

Why? Because this builds a wall of abstraction between the apps and the underlying tables. I can then constantly tune and tweak the tables and rarely have to make any changes to the apps. I can add or drop columns, change the data type of columns, merge tables together or split a table into two or three separate tables, but the views bring everything back together to how the apps expect to see it. They don't even have to know any changes were made. The apps can write data to what they see as a single "table" and the view trigger assigns the data to the correct tables. The view triggers know how the actual data is stored, the apps don't have to know.

Here's one advantage that is unbeatable. There are many, many useful functions that require the use of a *before* trigger. Sometimes you just really want to manipulate the data in some way before it goes to the table. Some DBMSs, even major players like SQL Server, have only *after* triggers. Such a pain.

But front the table with a view, write a trigger on the view, *et voila*, instant *before* trigger. This is even handy with other DBMSs like Oracle in that the trigger can update other associated rows in the same table without running afoul of a mutating table condition. I am at this very moment writing a trigger on a view that must update values in several rows every time any Insert or Delete is executed and sometimes for an Update. Almost impossible task without views -- it would have to be done with stored procedures rather than "direct" DML. Handy for me, handy for the apps. Life is good!

Also, take the loop condition caused by trying to keep two tables synched with each other. Any changes made in either table should be sent to the other table. But a trigger on both tables that just mirrors the operation to the other table will create an infinite loop as that trigger turns around and sends it right back. But a trigger on a facing view can perform the DML on its underlying table and on the mirrored table. The view on the mirrored table does the same thing. But since both views operate directly on the tables, there is no infinite loop condition to fall into.

So my question would be more like: why would we ever want users to directly access tables rather than have them go through views?

Comment: +1 for very good reasons. **Not the mention how awesome it is to have your question answered by Santa.** :) --- Outstanding beard!

Answer (score 0):

to answer the question on how to accomplish this with a trigger, you can use the following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.demo_trigger ON dbo.demo_view
INSTEAD OF UPDATE --The "INSTEAD OF" is probably why the question is in the course, outside of a view or procedure this is tends to be "BEFORE"
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON 
    ROLLBACK
    RAISERROR (50005,10,1,N'abcde')
END
GO
```

I added a custom error with this:

```
sp_addmessage @msgnum = 50005
, @severity = 10
, @msgtext = N'Not allowed';
GO
```

It can be removed again with this:

```
sp_dropmessage @msgnum = 50005;
```

Trying to update the view now gives this result:

```
Not allowed
Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.
```

Comment: Thanks everybody.

I get that and in the exercise I used 'INSTEAD OF' to stop any updates.

I was just curious as to why the option to edit a value (which does not appear in both the joined base tables) in a view existed?

I wondered if there was a real life scenario one might want to do that or if it was a clever solution to do something that cant be done in any other way?

But thanks for all the answers and comments :)