# Insertable UNION ALL VIEW on SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view

I have this schema provided and unmodifiable:

```
Table: Company1 Customers
+-------------+---------------+
| Customer ID | Customer Name |
+-------------+---------------+
| C0001       | ACME Inc.     |
| C0002       | Bogus Corp.   |
+-------------+---------------+

Table: Company2 Customers
+-------------+---------------+
| Customer ID | Customer Name |
+-------------+---------------+
| C0001       | Foo Bar Ltd.  |
| C0002       | John Smith    |
+-------------+---------------+
```

I need a insertable/updateable/deleteable view like this:

```
View: All Customers
+----------+-------------+---------------+
| Company  | Customer ID | Customer Name |
+----------+-------------+---------------+
| Company1 | C0001       | ACME Inc.     |
| Company1 | C0002       | Bogus Corp.   |
| Company2 | C0001       | Foo Bar Ltd.  |
| Company2 | C0002       | John Smith    |
+----------+-------------+---------------+
```

and I built it as:

```
CREATE VIEW [All Customers] AS
   SELECT 'Company1' AS [Company], [Customer ID], [Customer Name]
   FROM [Company1_Customers]
UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Company2' AS [Company], [Customer ID], [Customer Name]
   FROM [Company2_Customers]
```

How (if possible) can I tell SQL Server that all INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE operations in this view where `[Company] = 'Company1'` belong to `Company1_Customers` and where `[Company] = 'Company2'` belong to `Company2_Customers`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If I update a view, will my original tables get updated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648445/if-i-update-a-view-will-my-original-tables-get-updated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by creating an `INSTEAD OF` trigger for inserts/updates/deletes.

You can inspect the `inserted` and `deleted` virtual tables to see which table is affected, and execute the proper statement based on this. Example for an `INSTEAD OF DELETE` trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_delete_all_customers ON [All Customers]
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE c 
    FROM deleted AS d 
         INNER JOIN Company1_Customers AS c ON
              c.[Customer ID]=d.[Customer ID]
    WHERE
        d.[Company]='Company1';

    DELETE c 
    FROM deleted AS d 
         INNER JOIN Company2_Customers AS c ON
              c.[Customer ID]=d.[Customer ID]
    WHERE
        d.[Company]='Company2';
END
```

For more information on creating an `INSTEAD OF` trigger, consult the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx) you'll see that

> "Any modifications, including UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements,
>   must reference columns from only one base table."

You have two base tables for each field, because of your `UNION` so this view can't be "UPDATABLE".

Your best bet is to fix your schema and have a single `Customer` table, with `Company` as one of the columns. Your current Schema that requires a `UNION` to query fully is not the greatest.